# How to handle Azure AD Authentication with Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core 2 application running in a pod.

It is nothing fancy. Just the default app created by Visual Studio, with "School/Work account"-authentication enabled.

My ingress points to the service at `/`

```
- path: /
  backend:
    serviceName: debug-ui
    servicePort: 80
```

When i hit that endpoint (`/`) i am being redirected to Azure AD login. I authenticate and Azure AD redirects to `/signin-oidc` which is normal for AD login. So far everything works as expected.

The problem is that the ingress responds with a "502 - Bad gateway", probably because the ingress sees `/signin-oidc` as a route to another (non-existing) service, but it should have been an endpoint on the application at `/` itself.

The application running at `/` also have `/about` and a `/contact` - which works fine when auth is disabled

The `/signin-oidc` is called as HTTP POST with the authentication token. (JWT)

How do i get around this issue ?

Technologies :

- Kubernetes on Azure ACS
- nginx-ingress-controller
- Azure Active Directory
- .NET Core 2

Comment: add another path?

Comment: Thx, but how should that be done ? If i add /signin-oidc as a path pointing to the same service, then the service would be called at / and not /singin-oidc - i guess.

Comment: @TechnoCowboy, have you solved this issue? I have a similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51258599/kubernetes-and-aad-authentication) about

Comment: @AlexejSommer, sorry about the late reply. In my case, it was because I had a
rewrite in the ingress. (ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /)
Removing that line solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  paths:
  - path: /tea
    backend:
      serviceName: tea-svc
      servicePort: 80
  - path: /coffee
    backend:
      serviceName: coffee-svc
      servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Yes that i know - but that does not solve the problem.
The application running at / (which is the main page) also has a path /signin-oidc (as it has /about and a  /contact - which works fine when auth is disabled)
The signin-oidc is called as HTTTP POST with the authentication token. (JWT)
(I will add this in the description as well)

Answer (score 0):

Using Flask (instead of .NET) and AAD works with nginx ingress with something like below:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: flask-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: flask-auth
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: flask-app
          servicePort: 80
        path: /app(/|$)(.*)
---
```

This has something like:

**AAD**

```
example.com/app  
example.com/app/login  
example.com/app/other-logins-urls
```

**renders html templates**

```
example.com/app/app-name
```