# Kubernetes and AAD authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

On configured AKS there is docker container with application that is using AAD authentication.

Based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress) there is also configured ingress. API is working well.

When I add to Azure Active Directory application registration reply URL with https prefix I receive error "The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application". And I see that in browser address line redirect_uri is starting with http.

When I add reply URL that is starting with http, then I receive "Exception: Correlation failed".

What I have tried: Add to ingress.yaml setting ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"

May be there is some way to force ingress run https instead of http, or there might be some AAD redirect configuration? Any ideas?

UPDATE 2: Probably http redirect is because of ADAL.

PS: Was able to find [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48476998/how-to-handle-azure-ad-authentication-with-kubernetes-ingress) without an answer

UPDATE3:
I have decided not to use nginx as ingress. Instead I am using now Load balancer. Soon it would be possible to use Azure Application Gateway Ingress Controller

Comment: change all reply urls to https?

Comment: @4c74356b41, do you mean all reply url's in AAD app registration? Doesn't help

Comment: Don't know specifically how to do it, but you have to make the authentication bits set the redirect_uri as https.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

> By default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443 using a 308 Permanent Redirect response if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.
>
> This can be disabled globally using `ssl-redirect: "false"` in the NGINX config map, or per-Ingress with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` annotation in the particular resource.

More information on this [on the Ingress documentation link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#tlshttps).

Comment: Thank you, @mihail-stancescu That's nice found and I haven't tried it before. But still not solution yet.

Comment: as mentioned above it redirects out-of-the-box and I found the nginx ingress and AAD to work when using regex https://stackoverflow.com/a/58521497/7061494

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a decision whether to use HTTPS or not. If this is just the start of a development cycle, start without it and get auth to work - but implement HTTPS as soon as possible.

AAD supports both http and https, but of course, the reply urls must be added to the application registration respectively.

As @mihail-stancescu says, ssl-redirect must be set to false, if you choose not to use HTTPS. In addition to this, you also have to ensure that your app does not make the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

Using curl with -L -k and -v options will give you a lot of information on what is actually happening with your requests.

When the http/https thing is solved, you have to remove any rewrite annotations you have in your ingress. (e.g. `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`   should be removed).

Now, if your ingress path to the service in question is e.g. /myservice, then the reply-url should also have that part of the path added ([host]/myservice/signin-oidc) - both in the AAD application registration and in the configuration of your app. (The path in the config should not contain the host)

If you are using https, then you must also have a proper certificate. You can use the free LetsEncrypt (https://letsencrypt.org/) in conjunction with KubeLego (https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego), where you can find some nice examples on how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, @TechnoCowboy I want to mark it as an answer, but the problem is that nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true" in ingress annotations doesn't redirect to https in my case. Trying to find what is wrong.